# Why awk -v not working

Tags: shell, awk

I have a function in shell:

```
ConfigHandler(){
    name=$1
    dest=`awk -v file=$name -F"|" '{if($1~/file/)print $2}' ps.conf`
    echo $dest
    echo "Moving $1 to $dest ...."
    mv `pwd`/$1 $dest/$1
    echo ""
    echo ""
}
```

In debug mode, I can see the value getting passed on :

```
+ name=topbeat.yml
++ awk -v file=topbeat.yml '-F|' '{if($1~/file/)print $2}' ps.conf
+ dest=
```

But I am not getting the value of `dest`, I want it to be `/etc/topbeat/` , where as

```
  awk -F"|" '{if($1~/topbeat/)print $2}' ps.conf
```

returns expected O/P i.e `/etc/topbeat/`

**ps.conf**

```
topbeat.yml|/etc/topbeat/
logstash.conf|/opt/monitor/tools/etc/
jmxd.tar|/opt/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax `/pattern/` can only be used for literals, not with variables.

You need to change:

```
$1~/file/
```

to:

```
$1 ~ file
```

Note that the structure of an awk script is `condition { action }`, where `condition` defaults to `1` (true) and `{ action }` defaults to `{ print }` (print the whole record, `$0`). As such, you don't need to use `if`:

```
$1 ~ file { print $2 }
```

Also, remember to always quote your variables:

```
awk -v file="$name" # ...
echo "$dest" # etc.
```

With a couple more changes, this would be the final result:

```
ConfigHandler(){
    dest=$(awk -v file="$1" -F"|" '$1 ~ file { print $2 }' ps.conf)
    printf 'Moving %s to %s...\n\n\n' "$1" "$dest"
    mv "$1" "$dest"
}
```

Comment: Oh! my bad. Thanks